# Unable to an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

find bellow code (HTML/CSS) that I´m trying to move a specific DIV but not able to - note that I used Bootstrap

HTML - The issue is with the div id "PlayerMain" that is unable to move to the page center

```css
body {
  background-image: url('../images/dis_bg.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  text-align: center;
  align-content: center;
}

.whiteBorder {
  display: inline;
  background-color: white;
}

.allPage {
  text-align: center;
}

.blueFont {
  color: blue;
}

#efi {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20%;
  top: 20%;
  right: 10%;
  z-index: 30;
}

.h1Border {
  width: 1500px;
  background-color: white;
  border: none;
}

.loginButtonImg {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.loginButtonImg:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .mobile-only {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="SCRIPT/JS/site.js"></script>
<link href="SCRIPT/Bootsrap/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="SCRIPT/Bootsrap/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="CSS/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="SCRIPT/Jquery/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="SCRIPT/JS/site.js"></script>
<script src="SCRIPT/Bootsrap/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row whiteBorder">
    <section class="col-xs-12">
      <div>
        <h1 class="blueFont">דודי,<br /> text, <br /><b>text</b>text</h1>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section class="col-xs-12">
      <div>
        <img src="images/efi.png" id="efi" class="mobile-only center-block" />

        <div id="treepodiaPlayerMain" class="center-block"></div>
      </div>
      <a href="https://someLink.com"><img src="images/login.png" class="img-responsive center-block loginButtonImg" /></a>
    </section>
  </div>
  <section class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <img src="images/bottom_icons.png" class="img-responsive center-block" />
    </div>
  </section>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//someScript.js"></script>
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) and *[mcve]*. Also, please only use Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button) for **runnable** examples. If you don't make it runnable, just use code blocks (the `{}` toolbar button).

Comment: js is only a function, see bellowfunction init(player) {
    player.show({
        //Required Parameters
        account: "code",
        sku: "225544448896",
        width: 900,
        height: 506,
        container: "treepodiaPlayerMain",
        //Optional Parameters
        showTime: true,
        popup: false,
        showPoster: true,
        showJumboPlay: true,
        autoplay: false
        
    });
} - note that I changed the function name

Answer (score 0):

I show you snippet just remove  position: absolute; from css where you write id #efi. and check it again

Comment: unfortunately, efi is an image that needs to overlap this div and removing this attribute I will lose the overlapping effect

Comment: I am not telling you to remove efi from css just change it to position: initial;